# File size not Changing countinously of file being downloaded os.stat(filepath).st_size

Tags: python, pytube

I am using Pytube to download video from Youtube and run another program(**Note:** the program is executed manually when download is started) and check the progress of the download. But the output is 0, 71 and 100. No other value is displayed.
The Pytube file code is:

```
from pytube import YouTube
url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ERMRVORGvZM"
r = "480p"
yt = Youtube(url)
yt.streams.filter(res=r).first().download("path")
```

The code for the other program which is used to check the size of file is.

```
import os

title = "Run Python script on clicking HTML button  Script Output on Html Page Part1"
size = 13370966
percent = 0
while percent < 100:
     path = "path" + title
     fs = os.stat(path + ".mp4").st_size
     #fs = os.path.getsize(fsp + ".mp4")
     percent = (100*(fs))/size
     print(percent + "% Downloaded")
```

I downloaded the file to get the full size I will be using Pytube to get the file size after. The result is same for both **os.stat(filepath)** and **os.path.getsize(filepath)** .Is this odd behavior with *os module* or *Pytube*. If it is due to os module then what should I do to solve this.

Comment: It's buffering.  The file is not being written a byte or a sector at a time.  The package builds up a buffer full, then flushes the buffer to disk.  There's nothing you can do about this.

Comment: And you should NOT be using a tight 100% CPU loop for your monitoring.  At least put a `time.sleep(0.2)` or something to let someone else use the CPU.

Comment: @TimRoberts By package you  mean pytube

Comment: Yes.  All file downloaders have to do this.  If you can get a progress bar from the package itself, they can be more accurate, but the files on disk will update in big chunks.

Comment: Pytube offers its progressbar but it is also giving same results